# object move towards direction it is facing

Tags: java, vector, graphics, awt, graphics2d

Im working on a 2d car racing game and I'm currently trying to get the car moving. I don't need the physics of the car to be realistic, I just need the car (rectangle in this case) to move towards the direction it is facing. So if i was to rotate the car right by about 20 degrees, I want it to then travel in that direction. But I'm not sure as to how I would do this (i've done a bit of research into vectors but didn't understand much). Currently the box moves in all directions but doesn't rotate.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Box {

    public boolean[] KeyHold;
    public double posx, posy, angle;

    public Box() {
        posx = 1280/2;
        posy = 720/2;
    }

    public void update() {
        KeyHold = Inputs.getKeyHold();
        if(KeyHold[39]) {
            posx++;
        } else if (KeyHold[37]) {
            posx--;
        }

        if(KeyHold[40]) {
            posy++;
        } else if (KeyHold[38]) {
            posy--;
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.clearRect(0, 0, 1280, 720);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillRect((int) posx, (int) posy, 30, 60);
    }

}
```

Comment: This can be done using **M A T H**.

Comment: you could associate a 2-dimensional, velocity vector `car.v` (with length proportional to the speed of the car) to each car, to represent its direction. When "updating the world", each car's position becomes (`car.x+=h*car.v.x;car.y+=h*car.v.y;`).

Comment: in order to rotate the velocity vector, you need a 2*2 rotation matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix